# I want to force someone to click atleast one radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make it so that a message appears (if it can be like the required off of textarea and input but if not that's ok) if the person doesn't choose one of the 3 radio-button options?

```
<div class = "radio" required="required">
<h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Meaningless text.</h3>
<label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" id = "x" /> <span>ex.1</span></label><br>
    <label for="y"><input type="radio" name="x" id = "x" /> <span>ex.2</span></label><br>
    <label for="z"><input type="radio" name="x" id = "x" /> <span>ex.3</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Make one active by default - that is how radio buttons are supposed to work anyway. Always one and only one active. See "benevolent paternalism".

Comment: provided the user is using a modern browser, you can just use `required` attribute on the radio buttons, or just use a default selected

Comment: @Floris that's not a good UX practice. What if they submit the form without looking at the radio buttons? Choosing from a set of ptions should be and explicit action.

Comment: In addition to what @gonzofish said, if you're creating a survey with radio inputs, having a default selected element could introduce bias for that option. Just something to think about.

Comment: @gonzofish - I was introduced to the concept of "libertarian paternalism" by the book "Predictably irrational" by Daniel Ariely. It claims that it's OK to make sure the _default_ action (requiring no user action) is something that you consider best for the user. Example - to be signed up to the company pension plan (the form they give you on day 1 is to opt _out_ rather than to opt _in_. If you do nothing, something happens that is probably good for you - but you have the choice). I agree that the same thing would introduce a bias in a survey - but then "no answer" ought to be OK too.

Comment: I'd say it's better to make them go back and choose than choose for them. What if you defaulted to take 10% of a persons salary but they read it as 1%?

Comment: @gonzofish - if they read 10% as 1% they need someone to make savings decisions for them... Seriously - you might not choose 10% as the default - rather, the number that causes the "maximum 401(k) match" (sorry for non US readers) - the best place for their money (50% return; heck you could afford a credit card balance to do that!). But we digress.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want no radio button options selected when the form is rendered in the page, and you want to force the user to select one of the radio button options.  Here's a bit of code which accomplishes this using jquery (I modified your markup a bit)

```
<div class="radio">
  <h3>Meaningless text.</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-option" id="x" /> <label for="x">ex.1</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="radio-option" id="y" /> <label for="y">ex.2</label><br />
  <input type="radio" name="radio-option" id="z" /> <label for="z">ex.3</label><br />
  <span></span>
  <br />
  <button style="margin-top: 10px" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript using jquery:

```
$(function () {
  $('#submit-button').on('click', function (e, ui) {
    var valid = false,
        $options = $('.radio input[name=radio-option]'),
        $message = $('.radio span');

    $options.each(function (index) {
        var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        //alert($(this).prop('checked'));
        if (checked) {
            valid = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        $message.text('');
    }
    else {
        $message.text('Choose at least one option');
    }

  });
});
```

You can certainly accomplish this same affect without using jquery if you want a pure JS solution (I don't have the code at the moment :)  If you're not averse to using jquery a solution, OPatel mentioned using [the jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and that's not a bad option either.

You can also reduce the overall amount of JavaScript necessary if you're able to use a select instead of radio buttons.  Here's an example of that code:

```
<div class="radio">
  <h3>Meaningless text.</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="">Select an Option</option>
    <option value="1">ex.1</option>
    <option value="2">ex.2</option>
    <option value="3">ex.3</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <span></span>
  <br />
  <button style="margin-top: 10px" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</div>

$(function () {
  $('#submit-button').on('click', function (e, ui) {
    var value = $('.radio select').val(),
        $message = $('.radio span');
    if (value) {
        $message.text('');
    }
    else {
        $message.text('Choose at least one option');
    }

  });
});
```